# Php basics: printing <?

Tags: php, string, escaping

Re-reading a bit about php basics, as to refresh some things and to be more accurate when coding, I tried to print `<?` in a string with the print function and noticed that I cannot find a way to do it.

I am a bit confused because reading about the difference between singe and double quotes, I thought that the only characters needing a special treatment inside single-quoted strings were the backslash and the single quote (as in O'Reilly literature).

Of course, the `<?` is not any kind of character string but I was wondering how could I print it inside of a string.

I tried to escape it, to put it in a variable, to use here document but without any success.
Actually looking at the source code in Firefox, I can see the characters are but they're just not displayed.

Here is my test-string:

```
print 'No space between <? and php if you want to avoid errors!';
```

I suspect it to be very basic but still I guess that getting all the basics perfectly straight is the way to go, so here I am.

Comment: Get use to [htmlspecialchars](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) your output, learn when and how to use it. Notice only one answer mentions it

Comment: Thanks, didn't know this function, got me have a look in the php manual and refresh my memories about htmlentities() as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This isn't a PHP problem. HTML interprets it as a strating of a tag and renders it as HTML. See the page's source.

### Solutions

- Either replace `<` with `&lt;`
- Or use **[`htmlspecialchars()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php)**

Comment: Thanks, I'll take the first one (less to write...)

Comment: @IamZesh: Yes, but the second one is more flexible (If you wanted to echo `?>` too afterwards, it would do it automatically for you!)

Answer (score 2):

HTML struggles with characters used to define tag elements. Try this:

```
print 'No space between &lt;? and php if you want to avoid errors!';
```

Also, if you want to programmatically escape those characters you can use function [`htmlentities()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php).

Answer (score 2):

There exist characters such as space, <, >, which cannot be printed unless you use a specific sequence.
To print the following in an HTML/XML output page, you must replace it using the following characters

```
< = &lt;
> = &gt;
```

etc...